# Store Hotel Availabilies with daily informations

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to store some millions of hotel rooms with some requirements:

- Hotel gives the numbers of identical rooms available - daily
- Price can change daily, this data are only stored in es, not indexed
- The index will only be used for search (no for monitoring) using the hotel's Geolocation
- Size: Let s say about 50k hotels, 10 rooms each, 1 year+ Availability => 200 millions

So we have to manage on a "daily" level.
Each time a room is booked, on our application, the numbers of rooms should be updated, we also store "cache" from the partner (other hotel providers) working worldwide, we request them at a regular interval to update our cache.

I am pretty familiar with the elastic search, but I still hesitate between 2 mappings, I removed some fields (breakfast, amenities, smoking...) to keep it simple:

**The first one, 1 document by room, each of them contains 365 children (one by day)**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "room": {
      "properties": {
        "room_code": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "hotel_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "isCancellable": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        }
        "price_summary": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "index": false
        }
      }
    },
    "availability": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "room"
      },
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "number_available": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "overwrite_price_summary": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

pros:

- Update, reindex will be isolated on the child level
- Only one index
- Adding future availabilities is easy (just adding child documents in a room)

cons:

- Query will be a little slower, because of the join (looping of availability children)
- Childs AND parents need to be returned, so the query would have to include an inner_hits.
- A lot of hotels create temporary rooms (for vacation, local event...), only available 1 month a year, for example, this add useless rooms for the 11 remaining months in the index.

**The second: I create one index by month (Jan, Feb...) using nested documents instead of children.**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "room": {
      "properties": {
        "room_code": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "hotel_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "isCancellable": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        }
        "price_summary": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "index": false
        },
        "availability": {
            "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    },
    "availability": {
      "properties": {
        "day_of_month": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "number_available": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "overwrite_price_summary": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

pros:

- Faster, no join, smaller index
- Resolve the issue of the temporary room, thanks to the 12 monthly index

cons:

- Update, booking a room for 1 night will make reindex the room documents (of the matching month)
- If a customer is looking for a room with a check-in on the 31st March, for example, we will have to query 2 index, March and April

**For the search/query, the second option is better in theory.
The main problem is about the updates of the rooms:
According to my production, about 30 million daily availabilities change / 24 hours.
I also have to read/compare and update if needed, cache from the partner, about 130 million of reading / possible update every (one update for 10 reads) 12 hours (in means).**
I have 6 other indexed fields in my mappings on room level, this is not a lot, so maybe a nested solution is ok...

So, which one is the best?

note: I read this [How to store date range data in elastic search (aws) and search for a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824365/how-to-store-date-range-data-in-elastic-search-aws-and-search-for-a-range?rq=1)
But my case is a little different because of the daily information.

Any help/advice is welcome.

Comment: That is so specific and has tradeoffs going in both directions that it's rather unlikely anyone will be able to give a concrete answer (unless they had exactly the same scenario). That's why there is https://github.com/elastic/rally: You need to try it.

Comment: Yeah, in fact if this is our data, nested model should be ok, because it wont be updated so often, but for the external data with push from partners, maybe raven or a managed queue could control the amount of  updates querries send to es. If some people got mappings with similar child mappings and could share some bench, would be appreciated.